# Updating sql quantity using php from cart page

Tags: php, sql, cart, updating

I have a page where users select a product (products come from sql database) and input a quantity needed.  They then view a "cart" page and submit the order which just sends a email to me with the details.  I am trying to automatically update the quantity in the sql database when they submit the order.

I think I would have to do something like the following, but I am new to php and sql.  I would have to take the original quantity from the DB and subtract the "ordered quantity" which is entered by the user and displayed on the cart page and set that new value.  Can anyone shed some light on how I might accomplish this?

What I think I have to do?:

```
$updquery = 'UPDATE "products" SET "Quantity"= "Quantity" - '. $product['quantity'] .' WHERE PID = '. $product['id'] .' ';
```

cart.php

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
header("location: login.php");
exit;
}
?>

<?php
@session_start();

if(isset($_POST['logout'])) {
unset($_SESSION['shopping_cart']);

}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$email = $_POST['email'];
// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'myemail@gmail.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' 
replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a 
message to.
$email_subject = "Products Order - ".$_POST['email']."";
// PREPARE THE BODY OF THE MESSAGE
        $email_body = '<html><body>';
        $email_body .= '<h1 style="text-align:center;">Products List</h1>';
        $email_body .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;margin: 
 auto;" border="1" cellpadding="10">';
        $email_body .= '<tr><th colspan="2"><h3>Requested Parts</h3></th> 
</tr>';
        $email_body .= '<tr><th width="100" align="left">Product ID</th><th 
width="100" align="right">Quantity</th></tr>';

         foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $key => $product):

         $email_body .= '<tr><td>'. $product['id'] .'</td><td 
align="right">'. $product['quantity'] .'</td></tr>';

         endforeach; 
        $email_body .= "</table>";
        $email_body .= "</body></html>";
        $headers = "From: myemail@gmail.com\n"; // This is the email address 
the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like 
noreply@yourdomain.com.
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST['email']."\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();   
 mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
unset($_SESSION['shopping_cart']);
?>
<script>
alert("Your order has been submitted")
 window.location.href = "index.php"
</script>
<?php
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">


<head>
<title>Inventory Cart</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/icon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<style>
*{
margin :auto;
}
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
border: 1px solid #ccc;
padding: 10px;
text-align: center;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #eee;
}  
tr:nth-child(odd) {
background-color: #fff;
}            
</style>

</head>
<body>

<h1 style="text-align:center;">Cart</h1>
<?php  
if(!empty($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])){  ?>
    <div class="table-responsive" style="background:white;">  
    <table class="table table-responsive" id="mytable" border="1" 
align="center">  
        <tr><th colspan="2"><h3>Requested Parts</h3></th></tr>  
    <tr>  
         <th width="100" align="left">Product ID</th>  
         <th width="100" align="right">Quantity</th>  
    </tr>  
 <?php


         foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $key => $product):
    ?>  
    <tr>  
       <td><?php echo $product['id']; ?></td>  
       <td align="right"><?php echo $product['quantity']; ?></td>  
    </tr>  
    <?php  
         endforeach;  
    ?>  


    </table>
    <div style="text-align:center;">

    <form action="" method="post">
      <input type="email" size="31" name="email" placeholder="Please enter 
your email address" required /><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit"/>
    </form>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <input type="submit" name="logout" value="Clear" id="btnClear" />

    </form>

    </div>
     </div>
    <?php  
 }
    else{
        ?>
        <script>
            alert("Cart is empty")
            window.location.href = "index.php"
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    <br><br>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You provided your own answer (query):

1) Set up mysql connection in the beginning of your script:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

2) In your `foreach`, add the query to update each os the product's quantity as you add them to the e-mail. Becomes:

```
foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $key => $product):
   $email_body .= '<tr><td>'. $product['id'] .'</td><td align="right">'. $product['quantity'] .'</td></tr>';
   mysqli_query($con,'UPDATE products SET Quantity = Quantity - '. $product['quantity'] .' WHERE PID = '. $product['id'] .' ');
endforeach; 
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: That's what I originally thought and tried.  I don't get any errors, but the database does not update at all.  Any ideas?

Comment: Try the query again, I removed the double quotes from `Quantity` and table name `"products"`.

Comment: Still no luck :( . The query works when I run it  in phpmyadmin by itself with the resolved values.  And I know from the email that the values are resolving.  This is driving me crazy!

Comment: Change the query to a `select` and dump it , like so: `$test = mysqli_query($con, "select * from products); var_dump($test);` to make 100% sure that the connection is successful.

Comment: object(mysqli_result)[2]
  public 'current_field' => int 0
  public 'field_count' => int 5
  public 'lengths' => null
  public 'num_rows' => int 152
  public 'type' => int 0

Comment: $qty = $product["quantity"];
            $pid = $product['id'];
            $query = "UPDATE products SET Quantity = Quantity - $qty WHERE PID = $pid";
            mysqli_query($con, $query);

Comment: I even tried setting them to a variable which seems to work (the variables) and changed up the query with them.  Still not getting the table to update :(

Comment: Just to be sure, is the column name correct? `Quantity` with uppercase? Can you try printing the error? Like so: `if (mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}`